# update error with php code

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, syntax-error

I have 2 tables, damage and appoint. In appoint I have the field damage_id and in table damage i have the field damageid. I take the damageid from another page with GET and i use a simple form to take the appoint id in order to give the opportunity to user to associate damages with appoints.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include('dbConfig.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $id5=$_GET['damageid'];
    $apid=$_POST['apid'];


    $result=mysql_query("UPDATE appoint SET damage_id=$id5 WHERE id=$apid") or die("QUERY error: ".mysql_error());
    echo"Row updated.";
    mysql_close();
    }
    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">
<table>

<tr>
<td>ID APPOINTMENT</td>
<td><input name="apid" type="text"> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

As a result a take this error:"QUERY error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id=2' at line 1"
Any ideas?

Comment: Your input value `id5` is a string, right? And BTW your code is wide open for SQL injections. Always escape your user input.

Comment: It looks like the `$id5`is empty. can you check this.

Comment: id5 is an int is the damageid i take from other page!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is wrong.

Change this:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE appoint SET damage_id=$id5 WHERE id=$apid") or die("QUERY error: ".mysql_error());
```

to:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE appoint SET damage_id = '$id5' WHERE id = '$apid'") or die("QUERY error: ".mysql_error());
```

Also, as you've stated that, you get your `$_GET` parameter from another page as `<a href="editdamage.php?id='.$row['damageid'].'">`,

Change this:

```
$id5=$_GET['damageid']
```

to this:

```
$id5 = $_GET['id']
```

On the other hand, you should better make your queries with [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [`MySQLi`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: i do that it prints row updated but it does not change anything!

Comment: are you sure  `$id5` is not empty, can you add `var_dump($id5)` before the query and paste the result here?

Comment: its NULL but in other page i have this parto of the code: print '<td> <a href="editdamage.php?id='.$row['damageid'].'"> EDIT </a> </td>';

Comment: change in your code this `$id5=$_GET['damageid'];` to  `$id5=$_GET['id'];` then.

Comment: yes and sorry i find it! and can i ask you something? if i have in a completely other page an $id='.$row[userid]. for exampla i must change my above code to id1='.row['damageid']?

Comment: if the other page is about another thing and again you are redirecting it to this page too, yes you may need to change your variables and the update query according to this, but if you are asking whether creating same variables names within different pages would create a problem, no they don't.

also, please accept the questions if the answers are true and matching your needs to make people answer your questions in the future too.

Comment: ok thnx! i am newbie in forum and with time I will figure out about accept comments and the other staff!